# My phone can not visit the server on macos in the same local network

Tags: networking

I got a same nodejs server on two computers, one windows, one macos.

Through local network, I can visit the server on windows but not macos from my mobile phone(some WiFi),
but, but the windows computer can visit the server on macos. That's wizard.

Please help me if you have some advises. Thanks.

I expect access the server on macos from mobile phone.